# Questions About Home Water Filter

Tags: plumbing, water, filter

My questions (pics below):

1. How do these things work and does it actually make a difference?
2. There is dirt inside of the water filter - does it need to be washed out?
3. Do the white rocks inside of the water filter need to be replaced? How often?
4. What does the message WaterHard:20 Grn mean? What should I set it to?
5. Why does my flow rate show 0 gpm?
6. Where do I pour the bottle of Pur Gard?

Here is the water filter that came with the house I bought:

[image]

Here is the inside of it:

[image]

And a couple messages:

[image]
[image]

And a bottle of Pur Gard:

[image]

Comment: You should be able to find information about it by doing Google searches.

Comment: FYI, that's a water softener, not a water filter, though it may include a filter.

Comment: Any update on this? Did you find out how this unit works or how to service it?